# How do I get the item selected in the UIPickerView with NSIntegerMax?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, nsinteger

I'm new to Objective-C, and I already have a button with a function to go when the press the button.  In the UIPickerView it has lots of numbers going up until who knows how long.  I used this code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
     return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     // Near-infinite number of rows.
     return NSIntegerMax;

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];

}
```

I just need the number that was entered in all three components.

Answer (score 2):

The value for each component is found in:

```
[yourPicker selectedRowInComponent:x]
```

where `x` is the component number (0, 1, or 2 in your case).